# JAX-WS SOAP :: what's the point of the Action attribute in WSDL's input and output elements?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

I am using the "standard" `wsimport` that ships with Oracle Java 7 in a top-down fashion (WSDL first).

So, I have the following WSDL fragment:

```
<operation name="sayHello">
  <input ns1:Action="http://zar.bar.foo/IHello/sayHelloRequest" message="tns:sayHello" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"/>
  <output ns2:Action="http://zar.bar.foo/IHello/sayHelloResponse" message="tns:sayHelloResponse" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"/>
</operation>
```

After removing the Action attributes:

```
<operation name="sayHello">
  <input  message="tns:sayHello" />
  <output message="tns:sayHelloResponse" />
</operation>
```

... and re-running `wsimport` (top-down) to generate stub code, everything seems to continue to work fine in client-server communication, just like before (plus the WSDL is much cleaner). So, what's the purpose of these `Action` attributes? What's the semantic content they carry?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528

Comment: Since the SOAPAction HTTP header is relevant only for the request why do I then need the attribute on the `output` element as well? There is also a `soapAction` attribute (from a different namespace) on the `operation` element that I've seen being used (as opposed to the `Action` attribute on the `input` and `output` elements).

Comment: This should be the correct specification http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-metadata/#actioninwsdl . So this is a generalisation probably based on `SOAPAction`.